# Deleting CAMetalLayer for NSView

Tags: calayer, nsview, metal

I have a custom `NSView` class which is layer backed. I make a `CAMetalLayer` for this `NSView` which is created in `makeBackingLayer`.

In `makeBackingLayer` I create a layer `CAMetalLayer *backingLayer = [CAMetalLayer layer];` and set properties as required by me.

My question is, do I need to `dealloc` this layer explicitly while destructing `NSView`?
I do not create this layer in an overridden function, is it my responsibility to delete this or the NSView will take care of it?

I do not see any documentation around this. Moreover, all the samples that I see do not mention about deleting layers anywhere.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely do not need to manually free your layer. Assuming your program has ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) enabled, your `NSView` should automatically free whichever `CALayer` is set to its `.layer` property upon its destruction.

If you're not sure if ARC is enabled, you can go to Build Settings in your Xcode project and search for Automatic Reference Counting. It's been on by default for new Xcode projects for several years now.

**Note:** Your `NSView` will only be able to free your layer if it is the only object holding a reference to it. If other objects in your program are holding references to your `CAMetalLayer`, your layer would not be freed until they remove their references.

Comment: And even if the project is not using ARC, `[CAMetalLayer layer]` returns a +0 reference and `-makeBackingLayer` is supposed to return a +0 reference (nicely matching). So, if the frameworks need/want the layer to stick around, they are responsible for retaining and releasing it. The OP would only be responsible for matching any explicit retains they do with (auto)releases or, if using a strong property, releasing the reference in `-dealloc` as required with all strong properties. Nothing specific to the layer situation.

Comment: @KenThomases How can I check that `[CAMetalLayer layer]` returns a +0 reference? I can't seem to find such things in the documentation. Is there some place where this is documented in such details?

Comment: @user007 In Cocoa, the memory management is based on [method-naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html). If a method's name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy”, it returns a +1 reference; otherwise, it returns +0.

Comment: @KenThomases Thank you so much!

Comment: @user007 By the way,if you're looking to experimentally prove this behavior, you could take a weak pointer (using__weak) to your layer, and confirm in the debugger that the object is gone after the view is freed. Alternatively, you could just override dealloc and log it to confirm it is getting called (assuming your CAMetalLayer is subclassed).

Comment: @ldoogy I'll do that. Thanks! :)